# Getting listView child on itemClicked

Tags: android, listview, childviews

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id)
    {   
        //Get childViews here and set their click listener from here not from adapter 
        // something like view.forward_icon.setOnClick(...)
}});
```

I simply like to get the ListView item childs here and set their text or put an event from here not from adapter. can someone guide me how to do this. I have done it before but forget to use the technique. here is my item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_bg"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Mote"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="20 March 2015     17:00 to 21:00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/forward_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/forward_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to get the forward_icon here and set an onclickListener from here. I can do it from adapter but due to some accessibility issues . I want to do it like this.

Comment: U can call activity method from adapter class.

Comment: setting text and event listener from adapter will be easy. Why you are going the other way around?

Comment: It is a long story bro. but i don't need to access it through adapter. I want to access it from MainClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remember the solution by seeing the answer of @zozelfelfo and the other answer too.

The correct way of achieving the functionality is

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
            {           
                TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                // you can also get other listView item childs like this...
                tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Title is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
int childcount = listView.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
}
```

And then set the `OnClickListener` for each `View`, hope it helps

Comment: Now can i do this view.findViewById(R.id.forward_icon) with your view

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.forward_icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }

    });
}
```

EDIT: actually combine that with zozelfelfo's answer:

```
int childCount = listView.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
    View view = listView.getChildAt(i);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.forward_icon);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }

    });
}
```

Comment: thank you. But won't your solution only add the OnClickListener to the TextView after you click the list item?